# Using boost::phoenix to adapt a BOOST_CHECK macro

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-test, boost-phoenix

During testing when using c++ 11 I have used the following construct:

```
std::for_each( coll.begin(), coll.end(), 
    [ &obj, expRes ]( const value_type& val )
    {
       BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( expRes, obj.someFunc( val ) );
    } );
```

I am currently working on a project where C++11 is not used and am I a looking for a way to generate a similar lambda expression, without having to create separate  a function / functor.

I understand basic use of `boost::phoenix` to create lambdas,  but I cannot think of a way to create a phoenix lambda that is capable of calling a `boost::test` macro.

The best I can come up with is:

```
template< typename T >
void MakeCheck( const T& lhs, const T& rhs )
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( lhs, rhs );
}


/// inside some other function...
std::for_each( coll.begin(), coll.end(), 
    ph::bind( MakeCheck<bool>, true, 
              ph::bind( &MyClass::someFunc, obj, ph::arg_names::arg1 ) ) );
```

Unfortunately this approach looses the line number information of failed checks, since the macro BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL reports the line number of the macro, not the line number of the `std::for_each` call.

Is there a better way of creating a lambda that involves a macro call using 'boost::phoenix`?

Answer (score 1):

Macros are always expanded first, so the only way to get the correct line number would be to:

- not embed macros in templates
- or extract any `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, or other context sensitive macros from the template body by turning them into template parameters and wrap the top level expression (macro or template) with a macro using these extracted values.

It's probably not so difficult to refactor the boost [code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/test/test_tools.hpp) to include these modifications (about 4 levels of nested code), but that wouldn't be easy to maintain afterward.

Comment: perhaps this could be considered a bug in the boost library?

Comment: unfortunately manually expanding (or partially expanding) the BOOST_TEST macros  does not get me any closer to the C++11 lambda expression. I would like to get rid of the separate template function altogether.

Comment: sorry, I thought your problem was the wrong error location reported by the test macro. I'm afraid you won't get a C++11 lambda without C++11, macros cannot substitute for that feature.